# How to use something like \label outside the table environment?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, labels, variable

I would like to ask whether there is any way to use a `\label`-like command outside a `longtable` in order to reference this table in latex? It would be also helpful if the label of the table could be provided as `\label{table:var}`, where `var` is a variable storing the label itself.

*E.g.*, my table is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c}
\caption{\capName}
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

where the name of the caption is given by a new command `\capName`.

I would like to reference this table in the text. The table is re-generated several times; therefore, I would not place anything after `\begin{longtable}` and before `\end{longtable}`.

Comment: Put the `\label` outside `tabular` and inside `table`?

Comment: Please add a minimal example, it will help us help you a lot!

Comment: My question has been edited.

Comment: the request for an example  was asking to make a complete document, as Ulrike did in her answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom labels by defining locally `\@currentlabel` based e.g. on \thetable:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c}
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
\end{longtable}{\makeatletter\def\@currentlabel{\thetable}\label{tab:A}}



\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c}
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
\end{longtable}{\makeatletter\def\@currentlabel{\thetable}\label{tab:B}}

Table \ref{tab:A}, Table \ref{tab:B}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! If I understand correcly, this works only in the case that there are no lines between `\end{longtable}` and `{\makeatletter...}`. Is this true?

Comment: No. As long a \thetable gives the right result the placement doesn't matter much for \ref. You could even place the code before the longtable, but than you would need to decrease the counter first. But be aware that as the label is outside the longtable, links from hyperref and \pageref is not reliable.

Comment: Oh, it is very nice and useful for me! Thank you again!

Comment: @Roli... If the answer is good enough for you... You could accept it (the green button next to it) and may be upvote it (if seems usefull to you)

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments, open a new question - and add this time a better minimal example.